# How to register a class by convention that implements two interfaces?

Tags: unity-container

Let's say I have a class that implements `IFoo` and `IBar`.  I want to register the class *by convention* in Unity so that I can inject it via either `IFoo` or `IBar`.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: was this helpful? Did you manage to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start from the `unity` without using the convention. In that case, you want to register the implementation and bind it to multiple `interface` you would probably do something like this:

```
container.Register(typeof(BarFoo), lifetime);
container.Register(typeof(IBar), typeof(BarFoo));
container.Register(typeof(IFoo), typeof(BarFoo));
```

The points using convention is to archive something like this. The example is really simplified and tries to point out what should be done. The assumption is that type is `BarFoo` but generally the type is each type which is defined within assembly so some additional logic should be applied to detect multi `interface` implementations.

```
container.RegisterTypes(
    AllClasses.FromAssemblies(Assembly.Load("AssemblyName")),
    type => new[] { typeof(BarFoo), typeof(IFoo), typeof(IBar) },
    WithName.Default,
    WithLifetime.Hierarchical);
```

The point is to register the implementation itself next to the `interface`, then the `interface` will be mapped to the implementation. If you don't register implementation then each interface will be bound to the separate instance of the implementation. IMO this doesn't make sense with `TransiendLifetime`...however, you have the possibility to tweak the lifetime per type as well.

---

n.b. Just as a showcase how it could be implemented

```
container.RegisterTypes(
    AllClasses.FromAssemblies(Assembly.Load("AssemblyName")),
    type => 
    {
        var types = WithMappings.FromAllInterfaces(type).ToList();
        if(!type.IsAbstract && type.GetInterfaces().Count() > 1) //more than one interface
        {
            types.Add(type);
        }
        return types;
    },
    WithName.Default,
    WithLifetime.Hierarchical);
```